# Css not loading in elgg framework

Tags: elgg

I downloaded all code and database from server and installed on local.but the css files are not loading on local. same working on server, please help!!

server image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8JSN.jpg]

local image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pFkc.png]

database settings on local

Table Name: elgg_datalists

```
path: C:/xampp/htdocs/elgg_backup/

dataroot: C:/xampp/htdocs/elgg_backup/data/
```

also,when i open any page it give me view not found error.

Comment: Can you compare the path to the css file in your page with the path returning a 404 in the console?

Comment: yes,i checked it is same

Comment: Can you post the code, is the error a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in another link in database in `elgg_site_entity` table change the path your local path

```
http://localhost/elgg_backup/
```

If it's still not work then change the base path in `htaccess` file to your folder path like this

```
RewriteBase /elgg_backup/
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: so what is wrong in my answer? did u mean RewriteBase was real solution to you. for me things works well even without RewriteBase

Answer (score 0):

There is another table you need to modify called **elgg_sites_entity**. Change it like this.

```
http://localhost/elgg_backup/
```